# Ember.js: Limit on http requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, ember.js, xmlhttprequest

Sometime my Ember app makes a lot of request per second to my server. There is a **limit** on requests per second on the server.

For example, 5 requests per second. So, when I make update to my 6 objects, Ember make 6 patch requests. 5 of them is ok, but 6th receives **503 error**. How to avoid this.

1. Is it possible to set limit of requests?
2. Is it possible join 6 requests into one?
3. Is it better to handle 503 error? For example, wait 1 second and repeat it? How it possible to do?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Do you have [coalesceFindRequests](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_coalesceFindRequests) set to true on your application adapter?

Comment: Why is your Ember app making so many requests?

Comment: I have a table with a prospects, select 6 of them and click button archive them. Each of prospect saved and each of them generates separate request to save changes on the server.

Comment: too many ways to solve.  maybe you can try Ember.run.throttle() to [spread out] the request timing?  also custom ajax or using EmbeddedRecordsMixin could be used to make "group" saves.. also you can look up `ember-concurrency` to create "restartable/pausable" tasks

Comment: @Kitler coalesceFindRequests is for store.find operations, but I have store.save operations

Comment: @Grapho I have such function:

prospect.save(), so I write: 

Ember.run.throttle(prospect, prospect.save, 1000);

but I still have the save behavior. What can be wrong?

Comment: @Dmytro the problem with that code is you are passing each model into the throttle individually and calling its save function.. so you are only throttling one model at a time.. which does not help you.. you want to throttle a single method which accepts a model arg and then calls save on that... i think that _should_ help more.